# NodeJS Express REST API insert into MYSQL error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Hi I am trying to insert a record into a MySQL DB from a post (using postman to test) for a REST API. I keep receiving a server error.  Here is my code (using async and await and expecting a promise in return).  Here is the router:

```
 *  Creates a new user.
 */
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  const options = {
    body: req.body
  };

  try {
    const result = await user.createUser(options);
    res.status(result.status || 200).send(result.data);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

And here is the Service (UPDATED - STILL ERROR):

```
   sql = "INSERT INTO users (AccountHolderUserID, isSubUser, parentUsersID, appBrand, accessLevel, accessToken, tempPassword, email, firstName, lastName) VALUES ?";

   values = [
     [options.body.AccountHolderUserID, options.body.isSubUser, options.body.parentUsersID, options.body.appBrand, options.body.accessLevel, options.body.accessToken, options.body.tempPassword, options.body.email, options.body.firstName, options.body.lastName] 
   ];

  console.log(values);

  pool.query(sql, [values], function (error, result, fields) {

  if (error) {
      reject(new ServerError({
        status: 500, // Or another error code.
        error: 'Server Error' // Or another error message.;
      }));
      return
    }
    resolve({
      status: 200,
      data: result
    });
  })
});
}
```

I added a console log right before the pool.query, and here is the response when I try to post.  Data is making it from the form to the query, but getting an Cannot convert object to primitive value Error???

```
App listening on port 8082!
[
  [
    '1234, ',
    'true,',
    '1,',
    '1,',
    '1,',
    '1312,',
    '1234,',
    'notifications@answeringmobile.com,',
    'Nancy,',
    'Flannagan'
  ]
]
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

Please let me know if anyone knows what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Please print console.log of user object before pool.query and validate the typing of each element of the object.

Comment: remove `set` from  insert query. `set` used for `update record`. Here is sample code https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Thank you, I tried and updated the code above, but the same error.  Console log is showing the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think MySQL expects each *individual* value to have its own question mark. You are passing an array of values expecting that it will substitute the whole `VALUES` clause, but AFAIK it has never worked this way. The error message says that it expects a primitive value and not an object (not an array, it probably wanted to say).

Try this:

```js
sql = "INSERT INTO users " +
  "(AccountHolderUserID, isSubUser, parentUsersID, appBrand, " +
  " accessLevel, accessToken, tempPassword, email, " +
  " firstName, lastName) " +
  "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

values = [
  options.body.AccountHolderUserID, options.body.isSubUser,
  options.body.parentUsersID, options.body.appBrand,
  options.body.accessLevel, options.body.accessToken,
  options.body.tempPassword, options.body.email,
  options.body.firstName, options.body.lastName
];

pool.query(sql, values, ......); // note: just values, no extra square brackets
```

Comment: Thank you, however I still get the same error. - TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED AS FOllOWS:

```
/**
 * @param {Object} options
 * @param {Object} options.body Created user object
 * @throws {Error}
 * @return {Promise}
 */
module.exports.createUser = async (options) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const User = {
    "AccountHolderUserID": options.body.ctiAccountHolderUserID, 
    "isSubUser": options.body.isSubUser,
    "parentUsersID": options.body.parentUsersID,
    "appBrand": options.body.appBrand,
    "accessLevel": options.body.accessLevel,
    "accessToken": options.body.accessToken,
    "tempPassword": options.body.tempPassword,
    "email": options.body.email,
    "firstName": options.body.firstName,
    "lastName": options.body.lastName
  }
  console.log(User);
  pool.query('INSERT INTO users set ?', User,  function (error, result, fields) {
  if (error) {
      reject(new ServerError({
        status: 500, // Or another error code.
        error: 'Server Error' // Or another error message.;
      }));
      return
    }
    resolve({
      status: 200,
      data: result
    });
  })
});
}
```